# What does cabal mean when it says "The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls"

Tags: haskell, cabal

I've seen this message pop up a couple times when running `cabal v1-install` with a suggestion to use `--force-reinstalls` to install anyway. As I don't know that much about cabal, I'm not sure why a package would break due to a reinstall. Could someone please fill me in on the backstory behind this message?

Comment: Whenever possible, the `v1-` commands should be avoided and the `v2-` commands should be used instead. The latter are the default from cabal-install 3.0 and onwards.

Answer (score 2):

*Note for future readers: this discussion is about historical matters. For practical purposes, you can safely ignore all of that if you are using Cabal 3.*

The problem had to do with transitive dependencies. For instance, suppose we had  the following three packages installed at specific versions:

- `A-1.0`;
- `B-1.0`, which depends on `A`; and
- `C-1.0`, which depends on `B`, but not explicitly on `A`.

Then, we would install `A-1.1`, which seemingly would work fine:

- `A-1.1` would be installed, but the older `A-1.0` version would be kept around, solely for the sake of other packages built using it;
- `B-1.0` would keep using `A-1.0`; and
- `C-1.0` would keep using `B-1.0`.

However, there would be trouble if we, for whatever reason, attempted to reinstall `B-1.0` (as opposed to, say, update to `B-1.1`):

- `A-1.1` and `A-1.0` would still be available for other packages needing them;
- `B-1.0`, however, would be rebuilt against `A-1.1`, there being no way of keeping around a second installation of the same version of `B`; and
- `C-1.0`, which was built against the replaced `B-1.0` (which depended on `A-1.0`), would now be broken.

`v1-install` provided a safeguard against this kind of dangerous reinstall. Using `--force-reinstalls` would disable that safeguard.

For a detailed explanation of the surrounding issues, see Albert Y. C. Lai's [*Storage and Identification of Cabalized Packages*](https://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/sicp.xhtml#hash) (in particular, the example I used here is essentially a summary of its *Corollary: The Pigeon Drop Con* section).

While Cabal 1, in its later versions, was able to, in the scenario above, detect that the reinstall changed `B` even though the version number remained the same (which is what made the safeguard possible), it couldn't keep around the two variants of `B-1.0` simultaneously. Cabal 3, on the other hand, is able to do that, which eliminates the problem.